# Mounting a custom filesystem module

Tags: linux, filesystems, archlinux

I have a custom filesystem module which is outdated but I want to mount it on my 3.14.37 Arch Linux Kernel.

I have successfully built the module, but I encountered some problem while mounting:

```
$ mount -t lwnfs none ./mnt
```

First I don't understand what is the 'none' in the command above, and it give me error in the following:

> mount: special device tmpfs does not exist

Here is the filesystem_type of the module:

```
static struct file_system_type lfs_type = {
    .owner      = THIS_MODULE,
    .name       = "lwnfs",
    .mount      = lfs_get_super,
    .kill_sb    = kill_litter_super,
};
```

Also, the link to the full source code here:
http://lwn.net/Articles/57369/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$ mount -t lwnfs none ./mnt

The "none" means there is no physical device or file to use as a file store.

That code is pretty old; you'd be better served by using the go-to reference for device drivers:

```
http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c4022/code/memory/understanding.pdf
```

Comment: Yeah, the code is pretty old, but with a few alterations I can make it compile, it's just I couldn't mount the device which I couldn't figure out where the bug is. @Oldest Software Guy